# SimpleXML Adding attributes to children

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to create xml file,

I have problem to add attributes to child object.

```
$this->myXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<start></start>');
$a[] =  $this->myXML->addChild('parent');

$y = $a[0];
$y->addAttribute('type', 'documentary');
$y->addAttribute('type2', 'documentary');
$y[0] =11;

$a[1] = $a[0];
$s = $a[1]->children();
$s[-1]['sample'] = 123;
$s[1] = 1212;
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<start> 
    <parent type="documentary" type2="documentary">11</parent>
    <parent sample="123">1212</parent>
</start>
```

This is ok for one attribute

```
$s = $a[1]->children();
$s[-1]['sample'] = 123;
$s[-1]['sample2'] = 123;
$s[1] = 1212;
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<start> 
    <parent type="documentary" type2="documentary">11</parent
    <parent sample="123">1212</parent>
    <parent sample2="123"/>
</start>
```

I try something like this:

```
$s = $a[1]->children();
$s->parent = 12;
$s->addAttribute('xy',123);
$s->addAttribute('x',1234);
$w = clone $s->parent;
unset($s->parent); 
$s[1] = $w[0];
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<start> 
    <parent type="documentary" type2="documentary">11</parent>
    <parent>12</parent>
</start>
```

It is possible to to add attributes to child?

Comment: The killer feature of SimpleXML is that your syntax does not need to be as verbose as yours. What exact output do you want?

Comment: If i have my object $s = $a[1]->children();
then i set attribute/attributes

Comment: Do you mean adding a given attribute to an unknown number of child nodes?

Comment: If I use this record `$s = $a[1]->children();` and `$s->parent=12; $s->addAtribute('x',21)` then my output look like that  `<parent type="documentary" type2="documentary">11 **<parent x="21">12</parent>** </parent>` because i'm in parent node, I try to do like this output `<parent type="documentary" type2="documentary">11</parent><parent x="21">12</parent>`